# jQuery Datepicker Insert NULL if Left Blank

Tags: php, jquery, sql, datepicker

I'm using jQuery's Datepicker. When the page is submitted, if no value is entered, I need to insert `NULL` into the SQL table. Instead it is currently inserting `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`. Is it possible to pass `NULL` in my insert using jQuery's Datepicker?

In the SQL table, which was created years ago, the Data Type is `datetime` and Allow Nulls is set to Yes. Nothing is set in Default Value or Binding.

Also, just to note, I am doing error checking and taking into account the possibility of SQL injection. Just to try and prevent cluster here and keep the code simple/easy to read, I'm not including it here.

**PHP**

```
$sDate = $_POST['sDatepicker'];
$eDate = (!empty($_POST['eDatepicker'])) ? $_POST['eDatepicker'] : NULL;

$insert = "INSERT INTO table1 (sdate, edate)
            VALUES ('$sDate', '$eDate')";
// Connection, error checking, execution, etc. using ODBC
```

I have also tried:

```
if (empty($_POST['eDatepicker'])) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO table1 (sdate, edate)
                VALUES ('$sDate', NULL)";
} else {
    $eDate = $_POST['eDatepicker'];
    $insert = "INSERT INTO table1 (sdate, edate)
                VALUES ('$sDate', '$eDate')";
}
// Connection, execution, etc.
```

I also tried adding a hidden field and using it if `(empty($_POST['eDatepicker']))` so the datepicker is not even used if it is empty. Even when I do this, it still inserts the same `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

**HTML/jQuery**

```
<div>
    <label>Start Date:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sDatepicker" name="sDatepicker" class="required" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>End Date:</label>
    <input type="text" id="eDatepicker" name="eDatepicker" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</div>

$('#sDatepicker, #eDatepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy"
});
```

I also tried splitting the datepicker's up in the jQuery and adding `defaultDate: null` but that did not work either.

Comment: Did you try using `NULL` as the default value in your DB?

Comment: Nothing is set in Default Value or Binding. Sorry, if this is not what you mean, I have minimal DB experience. If not where would I find that?

Comment: If you're using phpMyadmin, look in your table's field that you wish to be `NULL` and look for `Default` - if there's nothing in it, just enter the word `NULL` in it and save.

Comment: Would that affect dependencies?

Comment: That, I couldn't say for certain. You'd need to try/test it.

Comment: Hopefully I can find an article that has some info on it. Even though it's in development, I think it would be good to learn first, just in case.

Comment: I suggest you create another table and HTML to test it. If it works there, it will work for your production work. That's what I do.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability... enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for the suggestions. I'll take that route as it seems best right now.

Comment: @Brian You're welcome. And do look into sanitizing your inputs/queries. That's a "read between the lines" comment from `Marc B` -- he knows his stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply check if the field value is "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000" and insert null .

```
if ($_POST['eDatepicker']=="1900-01-01 00:00:00.000") {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO table1 (sdate, edate)
                VALUES ('$sDate', NULL)";
}
```

**Update**:
Since this value is not coming from datepicker.you should check if default value is set in db.

A quick fix is to  add a [default date](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) to datepicker and check that in php

```
$('#sDatepicker, #eDatepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy"
    defaultDate:"01/01/1900" //some date
});
```

and

```
if ($_POST['eDatepicker']=="01/01/1900") {
        $insert = "INSERT INTO table1 (sdate, edate)
                    VALUES ('$sDate', NULL)";  //insert null
    }
```

Comment: Seems like that should work but same result. It actually posts "" which I tried checking in the if statement as well but, again, same result.